# Is watching censored hentai haram?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, pornography

I am a 15 year old boy from Asia. I have been brought up as a Muslim since I was a child and I try to stay halal and follow Allah's path.
I was wondering if watching censored hentai is haram. Since it is censored I cannot see the genitals of either the male or the female. At best I can see the female's chest but that is as far as I can see. So, if I cannot see the genitals of either the characters, is it haram to watch?